# "На Донбассе" или "В Донбассе"?

Tags: орфография

На Донбассе, или В Донбассе? Почему не На Кузбассе?

Answer (score 3):

Оба варианта возможны. И оба - достаточно древние.
Ранее в употреблении просматривалась некоторая разница (ну вроде как "В Донбассе" - понятие административное, "НА Донбассе" - экономико-географическое), сейчас она почти исчезла.

"На Донбассе" используется пока много чаще.
С Кузбассом, кстати, ситуация аналогичная. Но к нему меньше сейчас внимания, да и украинский меньше влияет.

Comment: Чушь. "На Донбассе" - просторечие. Если мы, конечно, говорим о литературном русском языке.

Comment: Чушь - то, что просторечие?     
Вы неисправимы. ))) 
   
Stopkran, не говорите за литературный язык. Для этого надо егшо знать и приводить аргументы повесомее пустых ярлыков.

Comment: @stopkran, аргументы?

Comment: @behemothus  Неужели и вправду ситуация с Кузбассом аналогичная? И последние семь лет всё чаще говорят НА? Прожив здесь с рождения большую часть жизни, всегда и везде слышал и видел В.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Ну положим, не всегда и не везде, а именно там и тогда.  Нередко сталкивался с тем, что местные нормы использования топонимов отличаются от общелитературных. Я не хочу сейчас дискутировать о правильности того и другого варианта, но само существование формы "на Кузбассе" легко устанавливается. https://mediakuzbass.ru/kolonki/mify-o-kuzbasse/48201.html#/news-text

Comment: @behemothus Я тоже не о правильности. Благодаря статье из ссылки еще раз убедился, что предлог В использовался не только там, а везде (кроме суржика) – это была общелитературная норма (ни в одной газете или передаче нельзя было услышать НА). А сейчас эта норма размывается, но пока прочно держится в самом Кузбассе.

Answer (score 3):

В традиции советского периода языковой практики употребительным вариантом было: "на Донбассе". Пусть бы это было даже просторечие, но, во-первых, язык развивается от периферии к центру. Это означает, что распространенное в просторечии слово со временем становится нормой. Во-вторых, в русском языке, может быть, чаще, чем в других, норма объясняется не логикой правила, а традицией. Поэтому: "на Донбассе".

Comment: Изменения языковые в части географических названий произошли на Украине в результате политического влияния идеологов отмежевания Украины от России.   Этому также способствовало рвение журналистов наших отечественных СМИ, которые подхватили эти новые украинские нормы и ни с того, ни с сего стали их употреблять в своих репортажах об Украине. Тем самым, следуя политическим мотивам новых идеологов Украины, решили неправомочно внести изменения в русский язык и повергли многих блюстителей чистоты русского языка в недоумение.  Так что по-русски правильно: "на Украине", "на Донбассе".

Answer (score 2):

Донбасс - это **Донецкий каменноугольный бассейн**. *На бассейне* не говорят, поэтому правильно *в Донбассе*. Тоже самое касается и Кузбасса.

Для обозначения территории Донецка и округи, мне попадалось слово *Донетчина, на Донетчине*.

Comment: >> На бассейне не говорят
А "на Донбассе" говорят. Это уже обозначение некоторой исторической области, а не только географический объект.

Comment: @Пересвет, согласен с вами, более того сам я говорю почти исключительно *на Донбассе*, но нормы русского литературного языка более консервативны.

Comment: нормы политизированы.

Answer (score 1):

На Донбассе, потому что имеется ввиду территория.
На Руси, на русской земле, на Украине. Украина -- это тоже название территории, которое означает "край". Так Т.Шевченко писал "на Украине".
На Кузбассе -- правильно, так и говорят.

Comment: Да? А это куда?
~~~
*В Україну ідіть, діти,  
В нашу Україну,  
Попідтинню сиротами,  
А я — тут загину.**   
~~~  
зато Пушкин писал "В Укарину"
Внезапно Карл поворотил     
и перенёс войну в Украйну

Comment: діти — сиротами; 
Україну — загину; 
козацькії — весело;
витають — до краю...

Поэзия, да ещё такая, как аргумент?

Comment: Да, может быть, действительно, пример с поэзией некорректен, поскольку примеры и те, и те верны.
Вообще, нет никаких четких правил произношения в данном случае, здесь идет опора на традицию, а значит дискуссия наша смысла не имеет.

Comment: Да, здесь правило употребления предлога определяет традиция. И нет, традиция __не отменяет правило__: мы говорим "в Исландии" и "на Багамах", но __нельзя говорить__ "на Исландии" или "в Багамах".

Нельзя говорить "на Донбассе" или "на Кузбассе"! Это нарушение правила (исторически сложившейся нормы). Вы ещё "на Крыме" скажите!

Comment: Вы тут упоминаете правило. А как же оно звучит?

Comment: >діти — сиротами; Україну — загину; козацькії — весело; витають — до краю... 
Поэзия, да ещё такая, как аргумент?  
  
А ваша реплика - аргумент?
Artemyx скала, что Шевченко говои на Украину. Я привел цитаты, где он говорил "В Украину". Аргумент?

Comment: stopkran а кто это правило установил?

Answer (score 1):

На территории донецкого угольного бассейна.

Сам угольный бассейн - глубоко. Вы не в бассейне угля, а сверху его,
поэтому *НА Донбассе*.

Comment: Вы же не станете утверждать, что находясь сверху ванны, вы стоите НА ванной, а не В ней, не так ли? Уголь залегает В государстве Украина - глубоко  , шахты бывают и 1км, и вы находитесь СВЕРХУ

Comment: Что-то с пунктуацией происходит: знаков нет или не те. Прописные возникают на ровном месте. К чему это творчество?

Comment: В руках смартфон, клава крошечная, виртуальная.. В данном случае разбирается суть вопроса НА Донбассе или В, думаю, понятно

Comment: Ваш ответ правила Galina Avanesova. Она разобралась с сутью и навела порядок, спасибо ей. Вообще,.. какая спешка при отсутствии клавиатуры может заставить отвечать на вопрос трёхлетней давности? Пожалейте читателя! Кстати, нет ответа на вопрос: Почему не на Кузбассе?

Comment: Почему , очень даже НА Кузбассе, по той же причине, что и НА Донбассе...

Comment: На Донетчине, как правильно здесь написано ранее,

Answer (score 1):

Есть устоявшиеся сочетания, которые не требуют доказательств правилами, они стали аксиомами. Мы говорим:
на заводе, на фабрике, на складе, но в институте, в магазине, в библиотеке, в депо, в банке.
Так и с Украиной, и с Донбассом: на Украине, в Донбассе, в Кузбассе.
На Кубе, в Исландии, в Австралии, на Урале, на Памире, в Альпах, в Карпатах.

Answer (score 0):

Всегда писал и говорил "в Донбассе". Мне кажется, так правильнее. А "на Донбассе" -- просторечие.

Сверился на Грамота.ру. Там моё мнение поддерживают (категорично). Так что на этот раз инстинкт не подвёл, как оказалось.

Comment: А какие аргументы приводятся на Грамоте.ру? То, что работники ресурса категорично Вас поддерживает, ещё ни о чём не говорит. Нужны доказательства.

Comment: Ответ 2 Пересвет:

1. Насколько я понял, аргумент у них (экспертов Грамота.ру) очень прост -- такова устоявшаяся практика словоупотребления в письменной речи.

2. Я неправильно выразился -- вопросы задавались не мной, а другими пользователями, и неоднократно. Просто ответы экспертов однозначно совпадали с тем, что я думаю.